# Save Activity Instance And do not create in second Loading

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a project that has A `ListView` and some `Buttons`, and some `ArrayList` and `String`.
I fill out the `ListView` from a  `DB Query`, that takes some seconds to Load, and when its loads,end-user do something and go to next Activity Via `StartActivity(myIntent)` method.
When goes to next activity, it will be back to this activity and cause it has a `DB Query`, takes some seconds and even if network got problem, it get force close Message.
How can i save the whole instance of this Activity just once time and again Restore it in second time?
Im new to android, any help will appreciate.

This is my `onCreate` Method :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.type_of_dairy);
    // all methods, views, initials and ....
}
```

Comment: Where are you making the db query? in onResume?

Comment: No, in onCreate, i have just this method.

Comment: You mean i should write all of my code in onResume method?

Comment: No, you should not. There si some confusion. So, how is the first activity getting recreated from second activity?

Comment: Not from the first Activity, it goes to second activity, and comeback to first via StartActivity(intent) method.
I want when it comeback to first activity, it does not load DB Query and from the other side i does not want to use onBackProcess method.

Comment: can you post second activity code also ?

Comment: @T_O, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your use-case is that you need to start the first activity from the second activity using startActivity method. You can do the following to bring the existing first activity to front:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstACtivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
//intent. // Your code here
startActivity(intent);
```

Basically this flag "FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT" will bring the existing activity to top. So, your `onCreate()` method will not be called again and your issue will be resolved. In case you want to execute some code when this happens, you can use `onNewIntent()` method of the activity to handle the new intent and initialize your variables/fields there. Let me know if you have any doubts.